# Attempt to use pip for anacona fails

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I'm running Anaconda 3, which has the pip folder already installed, I've set the environment variables as suggested on various on-line guides. However, when I try to use pip I get the following error messages:

```
C:\Users\MYNAME>conda install -c anaconda pip
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Program Files\Anaconda3:

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    conda:     4.3.30-py35hec795fb_0 --> 4.3.30-py35hec795fb_0 anaconda
    conda-env: 2.6.0-h36134e3_1      --> 2.6.0-h36134e3_1      anaconda
    pip:       9.0.1-py35h69293b5_3  --> 9.0.1-py35h69293b5_3  anaconda

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

conda-env-2.6. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 162.90 kB/s
pip-9.0.1-py35 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 452.55 kB/s
conda-4.3.30-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 744.10 kB/s
```

So far, so good, but then:

```
C:\Users\MYNAME>pip install selenium

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.adapters import BaseAdapter, HTTPAdapter
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests.adapters'
```

I've set local environment variables to point to the following without success.

- C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Python
- C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts
- C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip

I've also set the security permissions to give full control over the anaconda folders for write and read permission.

What is going wrong and how do I fix it?  The ultimate purpose of this is to install Selenium.

Comment: Why you want to mix conda and pip?

Comment: I've no particular need to, but attempts to run pip failed.  I suspect an installation of pip is fighting with an installation of anaconda.

Comment: I read another SO thread which said they could be used separately but then pip should be installed for external python and not the anaconda python. So for anaconda python you should use conda